# VS2008 fails to compile old C++ projects

Tags: visual-studio-2008, manifest

Suddenly compiling any VS2008 native C++ DLL project fails. They have in common that the call the Manifest Tool mt.exe. When this tool is called it always crashes with the message

```
mt.exe has stopped working
```

The interesten fact is that the command line for the manifest tools is always

> /nologo /outputresource:"..\FooDll\Release\FooDll.dll;#2"

independent from the settings in the project properties. When I create a new native C++ DLL the command line changes appropriate to the settings. The manifest is treated somehow like a resource.

What is this `;#2` and how can I find and remove the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET setup was corrupt. Found this with this tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx